# Check version of magento

Tags: magento-1.9

My site is not working even, My admin also.
I HAVE TRIED **getversion()** method in app/mage.php
but still, I am not able to get the version of Magento.

Can anyone suggest me, please?

Comment: you have to call getVersion() not getversin().

Comment: follow this link https://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/get-magento-version-on-the-command-line.html

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, Yes I have tried the same I have mentioned in question also. In hurry I written wrong spelling.

Comment: please show your code for more debug?

Comment: try this http://magentoversion.online/

Answer (score 6):

1. `You can easily check if a website is running Magento Enterprise Edition or Magento Community Edition hitting`
2. `Just simply write --> website_base_url/magento_version`
3. `After you will see **top of the left corner** some thing like... (Magento/2.2 (Community) or Magetno/2.3(Community), or Magento/2.3/(Enterprise) version...`

> **Check Magento 1 version using Command line**

**(Note : This cmd only for magento 1)**

```
php -r "require 'app/Mage.php'; echo Mage::getVersion();"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked versio n using ssh.

```
BY following these few commands - 
1. Login in SSH
2. cd public_html/<your directory>
3. php -a 
4. include 'app/Mage.php'; 
5. include 'app/Mage.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Question, You have typo mistake you have call **getversin()** instead of **getVersion()**
You have to call just like, `Mage::getVersion()` in your file.

You can also check version from your **app/Mage.php** file if you have file access of your project,

Search function like `getVersionInfo()` and you have display your current magento installed version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file "version.php" in root folder and paste below code :

```
<?php 
    include_once 'app/Mage.php';
    umask(0);
    Mage::app("default");
    echo Mage::getVersion();
  ?>
```

run file `version.php.`

Answer (score 0):

You can always find the Magento version number in the **Magento Admin Panel** in the footer area.

If you have installed **magerun** you could also use the command of magerun **sys:info**

Open the **app/Mage.php** manually and check the gerVersion functionality because it will be hard coded

Another way to check of course is through **MageReport**
https://magereport.com/

Answer (score 0):

This one helps you.

http://magentoversion.com/

let me know is useful or not.

Comment: try this too http://magentoversion.online/

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Linux try this command from htdoc folder

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs$ sudo ./bin/magento-cli --version
Magento CLI 2.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. php bin/magento --version
2. /magento_version

Answer (score 0):

For M1 run following command in webroot:
`grep -A6 'static function getVersionInfo' app/Mage.php`

For M2: view in composer.json in webroot or access this path: /magento_version

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but it may help someone.
You can check the Magento version (both for Magento 1 and 2) by opening your composer.json file, located inside the Magento installation root folder.

If you have ssh access just use `nano composer.json`